# Using cache service to mimiize propery store data calls duing large form submissions using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to send Google form data to external api, this api uses api-key to authenticate every requests being made. Hence I collect the api-key and save it in the property store.

Since multipl calls to property stores must be avoided, I thought using cache service is a google choice when there are large number of incoming form submissions. On reading the official documentation I am not sure I have understood well.

I have the following code that gives the api-key when called., I need to introduce cache service within it. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
function getApiKey() {
    var apiKey = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("API_KEY")
    if (apiKey) 
      return apiKey;
    else
      return "INVALID";
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that "multiple calls to property stores must be avoided"? Which kind of other cache service do you mean?

Comment: I want to introduce cache service

Comment: It *is* better to use Cache Service than to make many requests to Properties Service.  You haven't given an estimate of how many calls to the service that you might expect at peak use.  Is it 5 a minute?  Is it 50 every second?  Is it 100 times in 5 minutes?  You have also not given any indication of whether you've looked at the documentation, or supplied any code for Cache Service that you've tried.  The basics of Cache Service are very similar to Properties Service, except for setting a timeout period.

Comment: I time duration is unexpected, the students can fill a form. There could be 20 responses sometime in a second. Hence the minimum cache can be 1 to 5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An equivalent of `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("API_KEY")` with [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service#getUserCache()):**

`CacheService.getUserCache().get("API_KEY")`

- To write values to Cache use [put(key, value, expirationInSeconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value,-expirationinseconds).
- You can find a good documentation including samples under [Class Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache).